# Getting error when using function component in react

Tags: reactjs

**Hi can anyone tell me how can i convert these code in function component. currently i m using class component and its working perfectly.**

i am using these code for file upload with class component and same code i want to use when i am edit option. and for edit i am using function component.

```js
onUpload = (url) => {
  console.log('I have been clicked', url);
  this.setState({brokerLogoUrl:url})
}
render() {
  const callbacks = {upload: this.onUpload};
  return (
    <Grid className="CoomonT">
      <UploadComponent {...callbacks} />
    </grid>
  )
}
```

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Comment: i am not able to convert in function component. @ChristianFritz

Comment: and when i use this.setState({brokerLogoUrl:url}). getting error Object is possibly 'undefined'. in this.setState

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to convert class to functional component. You can do this.

1.Create `brokerLogoUrl` state using `useState` in function component.

```
const [brokerLogoUrl, setBrokerLogoUrl] = useState('');
```

2. Create the `onUpload` function

```
const onUpload = (url) => {
  console.log('I have been clicked', url);
  setBrokerLogoUrl(url);
}
```

3. Remove the `render` method, `render` just need when you in class component. And send onUpload function as prop.

```
  return (
    <Grid className="CoomonT">
      <UploadComponent onUpload={onUpload} />
    </grid>
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const MyFuncComp = () => {
  const onUpload = (url) => {
    console.log('I have been clicked', url);
    this.setState({brokerLogoUrl:url})
  }
  const callbacks = {upload: onUpload};
  return (<Grid className="CoomonT">
      <UploadComponent {...callbacks} />
    </Grid>);
}
```

Comment: `this.setState({brokerLogoUrl:url})` could be replaced with a react hook

Comment: Can u please give me a example